# Multiple of an Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is if a matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, does that make it by the definition of an identity matrix (only 1s and 0s), not an identity matrix?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. $2 \text{Id}_2$ is not the identity matrix, but it is diagonal with entries $2,2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identity matrix, by definition, is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are all equal to $1$.

Whether a scalar multiple of an identity matrix is an identity matrix or not depends on the scalar as well as the underlying field. E.g. over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, $2I$ and $3I$ are not identity matrices because their diagonal entries are not equal to $1$. However, over a field of characteristic $2$ (where $1+1=0$), while $2I$ is still not an idnetity matrix, $3I=I$ because $3=1+1+1=1$.